# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Im facing a problem here when im trying to split class attribute like that

```
     <div  class='message_holder  user1212 chatid142'></div>
```

so from my function i want to get user id (1212) and chatid ( 142)

But im getting the error in my tittle
how can i fix that pls.

```
 function user_chat_id(){
     classList = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/); //----here im getting the error
     $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
        if (item.indexOf("user") > -1) {this_id = item;}
        if (item.indexOf("chatid") > -1) {this_chat_id = item;}
     });
   this_id = this_id.replace('user', '');
   this_chat_id = this_chat_id.replace('chatid', '');
   return [this_id,this_chat_id];
   }
```

Edit :

and when i call it

```
  $(document).on ("mouseenter", ".message_holder", function () {
    var this_id = user_chat_id();
     alert(this_id);
   })
```

Comment: when is that function called?

Comment: `user_chat_id` its written

Comment: Are you sure `this` has the correct value when `user_chat_id` is called? Did you make any attempts at debugging?

Comment: @DanielA.White ok  i understand you i edited

Comment: You need to pass `this` as a parameter to your `user_chat_id` function. That being said it would be much better practice to use separate `data-*` attributes for the user and chat ids, instead of hacking around arbitrary strings stored in the class listing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its like that stackoverflow do . i have checked its chat page and everything is stored in class :) , is it wrong ?

Comment: Personally I'd say it could be improved, yes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that the value of `this` in your function is `undefined` (if in strict mode) or set to the global context (if not in strict mode) because it's just a regular function call.  So, `$(this).attr("class")` will just return `undefined` and then when you try to do `.split()` on it, you get the error you see.

I'd suggest a much cleaner implementation that uses a regex to get the numbers for you:

```
function getId(str, key) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + key + "(\\d+)\\b");
    var match = str.match(regex);
    return match ? match[1] : null;
}

function user_chat_id(obj){
    var classList = obj.className;
    var userId = getId(classList, "user");
    var chatId = getId(classList, "chatid");
    return [userId, chatId];
}

$(document).on ("mouseenter", ".message_holder", function () {
    var this_id = user_chat_id(this);
    alert(this_id);
});
```

In addition, the HTML you show:

```
<div  class='message_holder  user1212 chatid142></div>
```

is missing a closing quote on the `class` attribute.  It should be:

```
<div class='message_holder user1212 chatid142'></div>
```

---

Working demo:

```js
function getId(str, key) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + key + "(\\d+)\\b");
    var match = str.match(regex);
    return match ? match[1] : null;
}

function user_chat_id(obj){
    var classList = obj.className;
    var userId = getId(classList, "user");
    var chatId = getId(classList, "chatid");
    return [userId, chatId];
}

$(document).on ("mouseenter", ".message_holder", function () {
    var this_id = user_chat_id(this);
    alert(this_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class='message_holder  user1212 chatid142'>Put the mouse over this text</div>
```

Comment: I tried your functions , but i have two things to say . 1 im getting userid `1212,` with comma , and second how can i call the chatid ?

Comment: @ScooterDaraf - I fixed one typo.  See the working demo.

Comment: about the missing comma its my fault only

Comment: It worked now you are right , but is it much faster using regex with two functions compared with my function or ?

Comment: @ScooterDaraf - There is likely no meaningful difference in speed.  When you're doing things on a user event, a few ms one way or the other makes no difference unless you're doing it in a tight loop that is executed tens of thousands of times.  You should write code that is clear, clean, reliable, easy to maintain, robust, etc... long before you should micro-optimize for performance.

Comment: Ok i guess i go with your functions , thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

**Why your code is not working.**

`$(this)` will be current window. In that `.attr("class")` will be  `undefined`. So when you try to `split` it will throw an error.

*Demo for showing `$(this)` will be current window.*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        a()
    });
});
function a(){
  console.log($(this))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
```

**Soluton**

Pass the current element as an argument to the function.

Changes to be made

```
var this_id = user_chat_id($(this)); //While calling.

function user_chat_id(elem){ // in function definition
```

You should use `elem` instead of `$(this)`

*Demo for showing how to pass the element with it*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        a($(this))
    });
});
function a(elem){
  console.log(elem)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: `$(this)` will never be `undefined`, I understand the general idea but this is  technically wrong. Even if it were, the `attr` call would break first.

Comment: @Jon Yes you are right.  I have updated my answer. I have tested using this code. `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        a()
    });
});
function a(){
  console.log($(this))
}`

Comment: @scooter dataf Glad to hear that it helped

Comment: I wanna just ask jfriend if his function is faster with regex or my function and then i accept , +1 for both